# Error : Port gnuplot not found

Tags: macports

I have just installed macports as per the instruction given on their website. But as i type

```
sudo port install gnuplot
```

i get an error

```
Error: Port gnuplot not found
```

also for self update i get

```
Error: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
Please run `port -v selfupdate' for details.
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing
MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

It is same for any software i am trying to download using macport. How to solve this issue?

Is it because my college firewall is blocking downloads using macport? Which port do macport use to download?

And also if they are blocking it how come linux users can download using yum, apt-get etc

Answer (score 1):

You can run `sudo port -d selfupdate` to see why the update fails. I'm assuming it's because your local network blocks outbound access to port 873 (rsync), which MacPorts uses for updating. You should really ask your network administrator to allow outbound rsync – there's really no danger whatsoever associated with it.

To my knowledge, MacPorts is the only package manager, which uses the rsync protocol, so that explains why `yum`, `apt-get` and others work fine.

The synchronization failure also explains why the gnuplot port doesn't exist for you. MacPorts needs a file that tells it how to get and build gnuplot, which it downloads using rsync. If that never worked for you, you don't have the file and hence MacPorts assumes there is no gnuplot port.

If your network administrators refuse to open the rsync port (for whatever reason), there's an FAQ entry to work around that, as well: http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#selfupdatefails.